# How can I write this php preg-replace lines shortly?

Tags: preg-replace

I am gonna use it for a language alphabet. I wanna write these lines shortly... 
That is too long.. Is there any way to write it shortly?

```
<?php

$yazi="abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprsştuüvyzABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZ";

$yazi=preg_replace("/a/i","A",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/b/i","B",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/c/i","C",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/ç/i","C",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/Ç/i","C",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/d/i","D",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/e/i","E",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/f/i","F",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/g/i","G",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/ğ/i","G",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/Ğ/i","G",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/h/i","H",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/ı/i","I",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/i/i","I",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/İ/i","I",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/j/i","J",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/k/i","K",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/l/i","L",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/m/i","M",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/N/i","N",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/o/i","O",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/ö/i","O",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/Ö/i","O",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/p/i","P",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/r/i","R",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/s/i","S",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/ş/i","S",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/Ş/i","S",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/t/i","T",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/u/i","U",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/ü/i","U",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/Ü/i","U",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/v/i","V",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/y/i","Y",$yazi);
$yazi=preg_replace("/z/i","Z",$yazi);

echo $yazi;
?>
```

Result: ABCCDEFGGHIIJKLMNOOPRSSTUUVYZABCCDEFGGHIIJKLMNOOPRSSTUUVYZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this with iconv(), however it is not reliable. Try this:

```
function removeAccents($str)
{
  $a = array('À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'Ā', 'ā', 'Ă', 'ă', 'Ą', 'ą', 'Ć', 'ć', 'Ĉ', 'ĉ', 'Ċ', 'ċ', 'Č', 'č', 'Ď', 'ď', 'Đ', 'đ', 'Ē', 'ē', 'Ĕ', 'ĕ', 'Ė', 'ė', 'Ę', 'ę', 'Ě', 'ě', 'Ĝ', 'ĝ', 'Ğ', 'ğ', 'Ġ', 'ġ', 'Ģ', 'ģ', 'Ĥ', 'ĥ', 'Ħ', 'ħ', 'Ĩ', 'ĩ', 'Ī', 'ī', 'Ĭ', 'ĭ', 'Į', 'į', 'İ', 'ı', 'Ĳ', 'ĳ', 'Ĵ', 'ĵ', 'Ķ', 'ķ', 'Ĺ', 'ĺ', 'Ļ', 'ļ', 'Ľ', 'ľ', 'Ŀ', 'ŀ', 'Ł', 'ł', 'Ń', 'ń', 'Ņ', 'ņ', 'Ň', 'ň', 'ŉ', 'Ō', 'ō', 'Ŏ', 'ŏ', 'Ő', 'ő', 'Œ', 'œ', 'Ŕ', 'ŕ', 'Ŗ', 'ŗ', 'Ř', 'ř', 'Ś', 'ś', 'Ŝ', 'ŝ', 'Ş', 'ş', 'Š', 'š', 'Ţ', 'ţ', 'Ť', 'ť', 'Ŧ', 'ŧ', 'Ũ', 'ũ', 'Ū', 'ū', 'Ŭ', 'ŭ', 'Ů', 'ů', 'Ű', 'ű', 'Ų', 'ų', 'Ŵ', 'ŵ', 'Ŷ', 'ŷ', 'Ÿ', 'Ź', 'ź', 'Ż', 'ż', 'Ž', 'ž', 'ſ', 'ƒ', 'Ơ', 'ơ', 'Ư', 'ư', 'Ǎ', 'ǎ', 'Ǐ', 'ǐ', 'Ǒ', 'ǒ', 'Ǔ', 'ǔ', 'Ǖ', 'ǖ', 'Ǘ', 'ǘ', 'Ǚ', 'ǚ', 'Ǜ', 'ǜ', 'Ǻ', 'ǻ', 'Ǽ', 'ǽ', 'Ǿ', 'ǿ');
  $b = array('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AE', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'IJ', 'ij', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'OE', 'oe', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Y', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 's', 'f', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'AE', 'ae', 'O', 'o');
  return str_replace($a, $b, $str);
}

$yazi="abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprsştuüvyzABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZ";

echo strtoupper(removeAccents($yazi));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `preg_replace()` for this, you can use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/strtr) or [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) for this. Both allow you to specify a replacement array.

Edit: a few years back I've spent considerable time on the development an [I18N library](https://github.com/janoszen/I18N) that can handle languages with funny rules for sorting, etc, you might be interested in extending it for your language instead of writing your own code.

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace : can its first and second parameter can be a array.

```
preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject)
```

so combining your first arguments into a single array , and second arguments in other array, and passing those in function will solve.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
$yazi="abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprsştuüvyzABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZ";

$corr = array('çÇ'=>'C','ğĞ'=>'G','ı'=>'I','öÖ'=>'O','şŞ'=>'S','üÜ'=>'U');

$yazi = strtoupper($yazi);

foreach ($corr as $key => $value) {
    $yazi = preg_replace ( '~['.$key.']~u', $value, $yazi );
} 
echo $yazi;
```

or:

```
$corrReg = array('~[çÇ]~u'=>'C','~[ğĞ]~u'=>'G','~ı~u'=>'I',
                 '~[öÖ]~u'=>'O','~[şŞ]~u'=>'S','~[üÜ]~u'=>'U');

$yazi = strtoupper($yazi);
$yazi = preg_replace(array_keys($corrReg), $corrReg, $yazi);
```

Comment: both of examples say: 
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 2 in C:\AppServ\www\a.php on line 7